# unable to understand how Angular maps a json to an object

Tags: typescript, angular6

I was sending the following `json` to `Angular` client

```
{
result:"success"
additional-info:"something"
}
```

I was mapping the above `json` to an object of the following class

```
export class ServerResponseAPI{ //should this be an interface?
  constructor ( public result:string,
               public additionalInformation:string){
  }
}
```

eg. `let jsonResponse:ServerResponseAPI = res.body`

When I tried to access `jsonResponse.additionalInformation` key, I got the error that it is `undefined`. I suppose it was because the javascript converted the `json` to an `object` with keys `result` and `additional-info` (lets call it `jsonObject` and when this object was assigned to object of type `ServerResponseAPI` (lets call it `apiObject`), `additional-info` didn't map to `additionalInformation` due to different names. I corrected the code as follows and it worked

```
export class ServerResponseAPI{
  'additional-info':string;
  constructor ( public result:string,
               public additionalInformation:string){
    this['additional-info'] = additionalInformation;
  }
}
```

But I don't understand well why the initial code didn't work but the latter one did. If `Angular` creates an the `apiObject` with two properties - `result` and `additionalInformation`and notices that `jsonObject` has not got `additionalInformation` property, it keeps `additionalInformation` `undefined`. Then why doesn't `this['additional-info']=additionalInformation` also make `additional-info` `undefined`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know about Angular and Typescript is that Angular parses your JSON to an object and Typescript does the validation.

The thing is that when you're working classes you need to create new instances with the `new` keyword.

The Interfaces in Typescript are useful for types validation in coding time (they don't add additional code to your compiled code), and they are ideal for this scenario, which is to provide a way of "defining" the structure of the object which will be returned from your API.

This is how the Interface is used:

`let jsonResponse:ServerResponseAPI = res.body`

This is how the Class is used:

`let jsonResponse = new ServerResponseAPI(res.body.result, res.body['additional-info'])`

Using the interface allows you to map the types directly from the object.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo. I now see the difference between using a class vs using an interface. However my doubt still remains. Why did the 2nd approach work but first didn’t. I am using a class in both the cases. How does Angular’s behaviour changes if I create a property ‘additional-info’ in the ‘ServerResponseAPI’ class. Even though now ‘ServerResponseAPI’ has ‘additional-info’, its value is assigned via ‘AdditionalInformation’ which should be ‘undefined’, so why ‘additional-info’ isn’t undefined?

Comment: I haven’t validated it but here is my theory. When I did ‘let jsonResponse=res.body’, Javascript first creates ‘ServerResponseAPI’ and the value of ‘result’, is ‘success’ and value of ‘AdditionalInfo’ is ‘something’. If ‘additional-info’ is defined in the class then its value is also set to ‘something’ due to the assignment statement in the constructor. Now javascript executes the assignment of ‘res.body’ to ‘jsonResponse’. As json doesnt contain ‘Additonalinformation’, the previously defined property in ‘jsonResponse’ is overwritten to ‘undefined’.